# 3d Wall sliding collision

Tags: xna, c#, 3d, collision-detection

I'm working on collision for walls in my game and the way I currently have it I get stuck walking into a wall. I'm trying to make my character slide on the walls but still collide.

My character moves off of a vector I create using the angle he is facing.

this is my collision function:

```
    private static bool CheckForCollisions(ref Crate c1, ref Player c2,bool direction)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < c1.model.Meshes.Count; i++)
        {
            // Check whether the bounding boxes of the two cubes intersect.
            BoundingSphere c1BoundingSphere = c1.model.Meshes[i].BoundingSphere;
            c1BoundingSphere.Center += c1.position + new Vector3(2, 0, 2);
            c1BoundingSphere.Radius = c1BoundingSphere.Radius / 1.5f;

            for (int j = 0; j < c2.model.Meshes.Count; j++)
            {
                BoundingSphere c2BoundingSphere = c2.model.Meshes[j].BoundingSphere;
                if (direction)
                    c2BoundingSphere.Center += c2.position + new Vector3(c2.getPlannedDirection().X, 0, 0);
                else if (!direction)
                    c2BoundingSphere.Center += c2.position + new Vector3(0, 0, c2.getPlannedDirection().Y);
                //c2BoundingSphere.Center += c2.position;

                if (c1BoundingSphere.Intersects(c2BoundingSphere))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This is my update:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 29; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= 29; y++)
            {
                if (crate[x, y].getType() == 11 && collisionEnabled)
                { 
                    if (CheckForCollisions(ref crate[x, y], ref player,true))
                    {
                        player.clearPlannedDirectionX();
                        //Console.Write(player.getPosition().X + "," + player.getPosition().Y + "," + player.getPosition().Z);
                        //movePlayer = false;
                    }
                    if (CheckForCollisions(ref crate[x, y], ref player,false))
                    {
                        player.clearPlannedDirectionZ();
                        //Console.Write(player.getPosition().X + "," + player.getPosition().Y + "," + player.getPosition().Z);
                        //movePlayer = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: why are you using bounding sphere for walls instead of a bounding box?? with bounding spheres, collision can happen much before the player reaches wall in case ur radius is large

Answer (score 1):

This can happen because the position increment may take the character inside the bounding sphere where you have cleared the planned direction. So unless your player has a velocity component in y direction, it might not come out.

BTW, shouldn't this

```
else if (!direction)
                c2BoundingSphere.Center += c2.position + new Vector3(0, 0, c2.getPlannedDirection().Y);
```

be (last Y --> Z)

```
else if (!direction)
                c2BoundingSphere.Center += c2.position + new Vector3(0, 0, c2.getPlannedDirection().Z);
```